# Complex ActiveRecord Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how to build this query.  I'm not sure if I should try to create a bunch of scopes and try to chain them.  Or do I put it into a class method?  Or would I do a combo of both?  If anyone could give me a short example it would keep me from jumping out the window, I've been working on this for over a week now.

```
class CensusDetail < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to  :apartment  
  belongs_to  :resident  
end  

class Apartment < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :apartment_type  
  has_many  :census_details  
  has_many  :residents, :through => :census_details  
end  

class ApartmentType < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :apartments  
end  

class Resident < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :census_details  
  has_many :apartments, :through => :census_details  
end  

apartment.rent_ready       = boolean value if apartment is ready  
apartment_type.occupany    = the number of allowed occupants in an apartment  
census_detail.status       = either "past", "present", or "new"  
census_detail.moveout_date = date time resident is scheduled to move out
```

I need to build a query that does the following:

```
- if the apartment is rent ready then do the following:  
- pull a list from census_details of all residents set as "current" for each apartment  
  -if the # of residents is less than the value of apartment_type.occupancy for this  
    apartment, then list it as available  
  -if the # of residents is = to the value of apartment_type.occupancy then  
    -does any resident have a scheduled move out date  
      -if not, do not list the apartment  
      -if yes, then list apartment
```

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.

Comment: i've tried using both scopes and a class method.  I understand how to create both, but only on much simpler queries.  Here where I am first getting a list of apartments, then I need to iterate through that list  one at a time and then query census_details, comparing that number found in there to the value in the apartment_type.occupancy, make more decisions from that.  I'm not sure the right rails way to structure this in rails between using a scope, a method, or a combination of the two.  I don't expect anyone to write my code for me, more help how to approach this.

Comment: Let me know if I am on the right track, if this is the correct way or I'm making a mess.  Here's what I'm doing now:

Comment: putting a scope in CensusDetail `scope :resident_count,  ->(id) { where("status = ? and apartment_id = ?", "current", id) }`, from there in Apartment creating a method called available with is doing the various iterations needed as I outlined above, as I am building it up I am creating scopes if necessary.  I think this will work.  If so I will post the code up.  If I'm not on the right track please let me know.  Thanks

Comment: I think once the query gets to the level of complexity you are looking for, I think it's best to just write it as an SQL query and call it directly. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#using-a-string-sql-fragment

Answer (score 0):

I haven't cleaned it up yet, but this is working for me, so I wanted to share.

apartment_type.rb

```
class ApartmentType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :apartments, :dependent => :nullify
end
```

census_detail.rb

```
class CensusDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :resident_contacts
  belongs_to  :apartments
  scope :get_current_residents,  ->(id) { where("status = ? and apartment_id = ?", "current", id) }
end
```

apartment.rb where most of the work is happening

```
class Apartment < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :apartment_type  
  has_many  :census_details  
  has_many  :residents, :through => :census_details  
  scope :rent_ready,      ->  { where(:enabled => true) }

  def self.available
    available_apartments = []
    rent_ready_apartments = self.rent_ready.all

    rent_ready_apartments.each do |apt|
      tmp = ApartmentType.where('id = ?', apt.apartment_type_id).pluck(:occupancy)
      occupancy = tmp[0]
      current_residents = CensusDetail.get_current_residents(apt.id)
      resident_count = current_residents.count

      if resident_count < occupancy
        available_apartments << apt
      end

      if resident_count = occupancy
        scheduled = false
        current_residents.each do |res|
          if res.moveout_date
            scheduled = true
          end
        end
        if scheduled == true
          available_apartments << apt
        end
      end
    end
    available_apartments
  end
end
```

The code is a bit ugly but its so far passing my tests.  I would have edited my original question instead of answering in case someone has a better way of doing this but each time I do my question gets voted down.  If anyone knows a better way please let me know because I'm at a point in the app where there are about 50 tables and now it's all getting tied together with complex queries.